# Output is nothing when expecting "Hello world"

Tags: c

I am developing my first C project without any tutorial and I am making a VM because why not? It's an easy first project for people that know hardware and stuff(me). But for some reasons my non observant eyes can't tell why this is outputting nothing at all
(The "hello world" statement is written in hex and the SETCY is setting the amount of cycles the program runs):
main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

enum {
  SETCY,
  PSH, POP, 
  MOVR, MOVRR, 
  PRINT_CHR, PRINT_INT, 
  ADD, SUB, MUL, DIV
} Instructions;
int cycles = 0;
int stack[] = {0};
enum {R1, R2, R3, R4, R5, R6, R7, R8};
enum {SR1};
int regs[8] = {0};
int ip = 0;
int sp = 0xFF;

int getRegVal(int reg){
  return regs[reg - 1];
}

void setRegVal(int reg, int val){
  regs[reg - 1] = val;
}

void execute(int instr[]){
  for(int i=0;i<cycles;i++){
    switch(instr[ip]){
    case PSH:{
      stack[sp] = instr[ip + 1];
      sp--;
      ip += 2;
      break;
    }case POP:{
       if(instr[ip + 1] > 8){
         printf("Not a valid register\n");
       }else{
         stack[sp + 1] = 0;
         sp++;
       }
       ip += 2;
       break;
     }case MOVR:{
        if(instr[ip + 1] > 8){
          printf("Not a valid register\n");
        }else{
          switch(instr[ip + 1]){
          case R1:{
            setRegVal(R1, instr[ip + 2]);
          }break;
          case R2:{
            setRegVal(R2, instr[ip + 2]);
          }break;
          case R3:{
            setRegVal(R3, instr[ip + 2]);
          }break;
          case R4:{
            setRegVal(R4, instr[ip + 2]);
          }break;
          case R5:{
            setRegVal(R5, instr[ip + 2]);
          }break;
          case R6:{
            setRegVal(R6, instr[ip + 2]);
          }break;
          case R7:{
            setRegVal(R7, instr[ip + 2]);
          }break;
          case R8:{
            setRegVal(R8, instr[ip + 2]);
          }break;
          }
          ip += 3;
          break;
        }
      }
    case MOVRR:{
      if(instr[ip + 1] > 8){
        printf("Not a valid register\n");
      }else{
        setRegVal(instr[ip + 2], getRegVal(instr[ip + 1]));
        ip += 3;
        break;
      }
    }
    case PRINT_CHR:{
      if(instr[ip + 1] > 8){
        printf("Not a valid register\n");
      }else{
        printf("%c", (char)getRegVal(instr[ip + 1]));
      }
      ip += 2;
      break;
    }
    case SETCY:{
      cycles = instr[ip + 1] + 1;
      ip += 2;
      break;
    }
    }
  }
}

void debug(){
  printf("\nIP: 0x%x\nSP: 0x%x\nR1: 0x%x\nR2: 0x%x\nR3: 0x%x\nR4: 0x%x\nR5: 0x%x\nR6: 0x%x\nR7: 0x%x\nR8: 0x%x\n", ip, sp, getRegVal(R1),getRegVal(R2),getRegVal(R3),getRegVal(R4),getRegVal(R5),getRegVal(R6),getRegVal(R7),getRegVal(R8));
  printf("TOS: (0x%x)\n", stack[sp + 1]);
  printf("STACK: ");
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("0x%x ", stack[sp + i + 1]);
  }
  printf("\n\n");
}
int main(void) {
  //prints hello world
  //Hex = 48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21
  int helloworld[] = {
    SETCY, 24,
    MOVR, R1, 0x48,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
    MOVR, R1, 0x65,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
    MOVR, R1, 0x6c,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
    MOVR, R1, 0x6c,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
    MOVR, R1, 0x6f,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
    MOVR, R1, 0x20,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
    MOVR, R1, 0x77,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
    MOVR, R1, 0x6f,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
    MOVR, R1, 0x72,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
    MOVR, R1, 0x6c,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
    MOVR, R1, 0x64,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
    MOVR, R1, 0x21,
    PRINT_CHR, R1,
  };
  execute(helloworld);
  printf("\n");
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This looks like a good opportunity for you to learn to use the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set `int cycles = 0;` and never modify it. Then `for(int i=0;i<cycles;i++)` will exit immediately because when `i == 0` and `cycles == 0`, the condition `i < cycles` is false, so the loop won't execute at all.

As a side note: the stack `int stack[] = {0};` contains *one element*, so all operations that push values to it will fail.

Comment: Ah such a stupid mistake, Thank you so much! Have a nice day.